# jquery, emulate anchor click with rel

Tags: jquery, anchor, rel

Having this table

```
<table>
<tr id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to emulate a anchor click when user clicks a table row, something like the following.

```
jQuery('tr').click(function(){

var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

var anchor =  jQuery('<a />').attr({href:'index.php?id=' + id,rel:"{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 600}}"});

anchor.click();
});
```

I know how to redirect, or visit a link in jQuery, the question here has to do with "rel" attribute of the anchor.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the a tag to the dom tree.

```
anchor.appendTo('body').click();
```

Comment: Seems OP needs `anchor.hide().appendTo('body').click().remove()` to prevent it from showing. maybe `remove` is not necessary...